# Passing a variable parameter through a jquery click function in a new control

Tags: jquery, json

In the browser, I'm translating a json data stream into a set of divs resembling rows in a table, with spans that resemble cells in the rows.

One of the spans is a help button, that needs to have a click function, which needs to have a parameter identifying the help information to display. The parameter comes from the json "row" data.

The code for building the "rows" and "cells" works fine, except for the help button which is shown here:

```
    var wrkNameOrIDCode 

    // in this next, wrkData[i] is the "row", 
    // and wrkData[i]["NameOrIDCode"] produces the correct help code value

    wrkNameOrIDCode = wrkData[i]["NameOrIDCode"]  

    $wrkHelpBtn = $('<span>', {  // this is the gelp button element
    id: "ACTV_" + i.toString() + "_HelpBtn",
    click: (function () {
                RspHelp(wrkNameOrIDCode, "-"); // the "normal" way to call the help function
                return false;
            }),
    }),
    class: "ARC_Help",
    html:"?"
    })
```

The above case doesn't work, because it always sends the last row value of this:

```
wrkNameOrIDCode = wrkData[i]["NameOrIDCode"]
```

I also tried it with the click function set up like this:

```
click: ({ param1: wrkNameOrIDCode },
   function () {
   RspHelpFromActv();
   return false;
   }),

// then, elsewhere
function RspHelpFromActv(event) {
    RspHelp(event.data.param1, "-")
}
```

However, the second case doesn't work because it says the event is undefined when it gets to RspHelpFromActv.

I've read about the need for a local variable and as shown I tried to use the jquery data function, but no joy.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your puzzle is due to this line:

```
RspHelp(wrkNameOrIDCode, "-");
```

It calls the function called "RspHelp" passing in the value of the variable called "wrkNameOrIDCode".  The problem for you is that as you go through your loop building your rows, this variable changes and at the end of the loop, the variable holds its **last** value.  As such when the function is called and it passes in the "current" value of the variable, you get the result that you don't want.  The trick is to pass the value of the variable in effect **at the time that the definition was made**.

This cane be achieved using the [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) function.

For example:

```
click: $.proxy(function(currentWrkNameORIDCode) {
    RspHelp(currentWrkNameORIDCode, "-"); // the "normal" way to call the help function
    return false;
}, this, wrkNameOrIDCode);
```

**Note:** I haven't syntax checked this so please use it for illustration only.  I'd suggest studying the jQuery.proxy() function in detail.

Comment: Worked as coded above.  Kind of scary, because so much black box.  I realized later I could just take the "this" and use it to work back through the HTML to find the "NameOrIDCode" in a hidden field.  This is more elegant, for sure.  I guess from reading the jquery description
    =>jQuery.proxy( function, context [, additionalArguments ] )<=
that the "this" is the "context", and the "currentWrkNameORIDCode" is a "proxy" hah hah for the actual value of wrkNameOrIDCode, which automagically gets swapped in there.